# NoneType error has no shape error on face mask detection

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying a real-time face mask detection code but I stumbled upon an error in the stream code which reads below. Any idea on the fix? Thanks in advance

````
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=1).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 500)

    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)

        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break ```

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py in resize(image, width, height, inter)
---> 69     (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
````